# Can the structure group be different than the Lie group fiber of a principal bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles

Let $\pi: P \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle whose fibers are a Lie group $G$. In Hamilton's *Mathematical Gauge Theory* he states that

> The group $G$ is called the **structure group** of the principal bundle.

I was left thinking that the term structure group is another way to refer to the fiber of a principal bundle.

However, I have also come across other resources (such as this question: [What is the structure group of the tangent bundle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422658/what-is-the-structure-group-of-the-tangent-bundle)) that gives a more general definition where the structure group can be completely different than the fiber. From what I have understood of their definition, let $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ be a fiber bundle with fiber $F$. If $u$ is in the domain of two trivializations $\phi_1: E \rightarrow M \times F$ and $\phi_2: E \rightarrow M \times F$, with images $\phi_1(u) = (x, f_1)$ and $\phi_2(u) = (x, f_2)$, then the structure group $G$ of the fiber bundle is a group whose group action relates these two images, namely $f_1 = g \cdot f_2$ for some $g \in G$.

I am now a little confused on what the structure group is exactly and how it relates to the fiber of a fiber bundle, especially in the context of principal bundles. In the case where we have a principal $G$-bundle is the structure group always the same as the fiber (and hence the Lie group) $G$ or can it be generalized to another group?

Comment: Are you familiar with associated bundles of a principal bundle? For instance: the tangent bundle $TM$ of a smooth manifold $M$ has as fibers the tangent spaces $T_pM$. It is an associated bundle to the so-called frame bundle $FM$ of $M$, which is a principal $\mathrm{GL}(\dim(M),\mathbb R)$-bundle.

Comment: @NicoZimmer I am familiar with frame bundles but I have not yet gotten to the section on associated bundles in the book.

Comment: My point being, that the fibers of a principal $G$-bundle are always diffeomorphic to the Lie group $G$. However the fibers of a generic fiber bundle (for instance an associated bundle) typically don't have to be.

Comment: @NicoZimmer Thank you, I think I get it now. So in the case of a principal $G$-bundle, the structure group is always the same/diffeomorphic to the Lie group $G$.  However for a general fiber bundle the structure group has no predetermined form/relation to its fibers. Is that right?

Comment: I'd be careful with the phrasing. "The" structure group isn't unique as adding additional structure to a fiber bundle can be equivalent to reducing "the" structure group to a subgroup. However in the setting of principal $G$-bundles we already provide the relevant group to begin with and any associated bundle to this principal $G$-bundle will have the very same Lie group $G$ as structure group. Generally I'd recommend to think about the structure group as additional structure and not a property of a fiber bundle per se.

Comment: Regarding your last question: Of course there is a relation between "the" structure group and the fiber $F$, since the structure group usually (if the group acts faithfully from the left on the fiber $F$) can be taken to be the diffeomorphisms of $F$ or a subgroup thereof (assuming we work in the smooth category of course). But other than that the fibers do not have to be diffeomorphic to the structure group etc.

Comment: @NicoZimmer Thank you again. This sounds similar to a group action on a set, where the group is of course not unique and many groups can act on a given set, just in the case of principal bundles the group is already specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What’s in the link is actually not a more general definition, it is more restrictive. Here’s what Hamilton writes; immediately after giving the definition of a principal bundle, he says

> *Remark 4.1.3*: The classic references [133] (Steenrod) and [81] (Husemoller) use the term *fibre bundle* in a
> more restrictive sense; see Remark 4.1.15.

and remark 4.1.15 says the following:

> *Remark 4.1.15:* Some references, such as [133] and [81], use the term *fibre bundle* more restrictively. If the topological definition in these books is transferred to a
> smooth setting, the definition amounts to assuming that the transition functions of a
> bundle atlas are smooth maps to a Lie group $G$, acting smoothly as a transformation
> group on the fibre $F$, instead of maps to the full diffeomorphism group $\text{Diff}(F)$ of
> the fibre:
> \begin{align}
> \phi_{ji}:U_i\cap U_j&\to G\\
> x&\mapsto \phi_{jx}\circ\phi_{ix}^{-1}.
> \end{align}
> Equivalently, a fibre bundle is with this definition always an associated bundle in the
> sense of Remark 4.7.8.

So, *fiber bundle* as defined by Hamilton (and also other authors) does not come equipped with a group, whereas in the other references of Steenrod and Husemoller (let’s just take Husemoller for example) the definition is as the associated fiber bundle:

> **Definition.[Husemoller, *Definition of Fiber Bundle*]**
>
> Let $\xi=(X,p,B)$ be a principal $G$-bundle and let $F$ be a left $G$-space. The relation $(x,y)s=(xs,s^{-1}y)$ defines a right $G$-space structure on $X\times F$. Let $X_F$ denote the quotient space $(X\times F)/G$ and $p_F$ the factorization of $X\times F\to X\to B$ by the projection $X\times F\to X_F$. With this notation, the bundle $(X_F,p_F,B)$, denoted $\xi[F]$, is called the fiber bundle over $B$ with fiber $F$ (viewed as a $G$-space) and associated principal bundle $\xi$. The group $G$ is called the structure group of the fiber bundle $\xi[F]$.

Reiterating, note that although in this source one calls $G$ “the structure group of $\xi[F]$”, the very definition of *fiber bundle* is restrictive, in the sense that a fiber bundle is defined to be an associated bundle of a principal bundle (whereas Hamilton requires it to be a triple $(X,p,B)$ where $p$ is surjective and smooth/continuous and satisfy a local-triviality condition… other names for this object include *locally-trivial (smooth/continuous) bundle*).

Comment: I think it's really a matter of semantics at this point. I'd still argue that $\mathrm{Diff}(F)$ should be named "the" structure group of the fiber bundle, even with Hamilton's more general definition.

Comment: @NicoZimmer I agree, I was just pointing out where the semantic differences were (actually pointing out where Hamilton already points them out).

Comment: although, I personally don’t **actively** think of the diffeomorphism group as being the structure group in the sense that, because it’s infinite-dimensional I’d rather steer clear of having to interpret a statement like “the transition maps $U_i\cap U_j\to \text{Diff}(F)$ are smooth” in a literal sense by equipping the diffeomorphism group with a smooth structure etc etc. but yea semantics at this point

Comment: Yeah, I agree. However in trying to fully understand these concepts it is beneficial, IMO, to point out that the diffeomorphism group plays the role of the structure group.

Comment: If I saw "structure group" used with no qualification and no noted structure on the bundle, I would assume the General Linear group before the full diffeomorphism group. Usually though you see it used in Physics contexts where there is always a metric kicking around and they mean $O(n)$ or similar.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for your answer, I think I will have to learn about associated bundles first to properly understand it. However what I have understood (and please correct me if I am wrong), is that Hamilton's definition of a fiber bundle assumes no group action. Thus one may associate a group action to the fiber bundle similar to the $f_1 = g \cdot f_2$ I have written in my original post. Other definitions, such as Husemoller, do. This group is called the structure group. When the fiber bundle is a principle bundle we have a structure group from the outset (which is the Lie group $G$).

Comment: @CBBAM sure, but really its semantics; just keep reading and things will fall into place. WHat you really need to know are the main concepts (local triviality, bundle charts, trivial vs non-trivial, key examples etc)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Callum The general linear group does not always make sense as a structure group. If we're talking about vector bundles or frame bundles, however, sure.